# Debug wkwebview on existing production app on iOS

Tags: wkwebview

How to debug/inspect existing production app's wkwebview on a production app?

I've tried to use safari debugger but couldn't connect.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour] and read [ask] for suggestions to improve your question. Make sure to include a [example].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, you cannot do this. Only apps with the entitlement `com.apple.security.get-task-allow` can be connected to, and apps with this entitlement can't be distributed through the app store.

See https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/118415